Display cities over .tiff file using Python
I created this .tiff file:
enter image description here
How do I have city labels and county boundaries overlayed on top of it? Like so:
enter image description here
I'd like county boundaries and city labels over the interpolated .tiff map I created.

If this is not a great question for ChatGPT, I don't know what is.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
